# Problems finding Boost in cmake

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm trying to build Caffe for windows as described here:
https://github.com/willyd/caffe-windows-dependencies

To do so I needed to download Boost (which I have, version 1.60.0) which I extracted to C:\Boost\boost_1_60_0
In my environment variables I have set:

BOOST_INCLUDEDIR : C:\Boost\boost_1_60_0\boost

BOOST_LIBRARYDIR : C:\Boost\boost_1_60_0\libs

BOOST_ROOT       : C:\Boost\boost_1_60_0

I attempt to run the CMake gui with:

Source: C:/libs/caffe/caffe-windows-dependencies

Build:  C:\libs\caffe\build-caffe-windows-dependencies

Yet it fails with the error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1245 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.60.0

  Boost include path: C:/Boost/boost_1_60_0

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_system
          boost_thread
          boost_filesystem
          boost_date_time

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to     the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:107 (set):
  Syntax error in cmake code at

    C:/libs/caffe/caffe-windows-dependencies/CMakeLists.txt:107

  when parsing string

    ${CMAKE_INSTALL_

  syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting } (16)
```

Any one has any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Output of `cmake -DBoost_DEBUG=ON <source-dir>` please.

Comment: Unless you've done something unusual that library dir is incorrect. You need to build the libraries and then specify the directory that contains them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was using the header files only.
I resolved this issue by replacing the boost folder with the pre-built binaries and everything works again.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  I've spent 8 hours trying to build socket.io using CMake, but it requires boost and I'm getting the exact same error you got